# Error protecting file using MIP SDK in service/daemon application

Tags: azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

can someone help me with the following issue?

**Scenario**. I have a Windows Service running on an Azure VM. Service receives files, modifies them in some way (let's assume that it adds custom properties to Word files) and uses MIP SDK to protect them with template ID.

**Issue**. `IFileHandler.SetProtection(string)+CommitAsync(...)` fails with the following exception:

*One or more errors occurred. ServiceDiscoveryHelper::GetServiceDetails - Cannot compute domain: license domains, identity, and cloud endpoint base URL are all empty, correlationId:[9add32ba-0cb7-4d31-b9d8-0000b7c694a4]*

**Other info**

- `RemoveProtection()+CommitAsync(...)` work fine.
- I registered application in Azure Active Directory tenant.

  - Generated secret: `<CLIENT_SECRET>`.
  - Granted the following permissions

    - https://api.mipwebservice.com/InformationProtectionPolicy.Read.All
    - https://psor.o365syncservice.com/UnifiedPolicy.Tenant.Read
    - https://aadrm.com/Content.SuperUser
    - https://aadrm.com/Content.Writer
    - https://aadrm.com/Content.DelegatedWriter
    - https://aadrm.com/Content.DelegatedReader
- IAuthDelegate implementation

  - uses ADAL to get access token using `client_credentials` authentication flow, because there is no interacting user (my app is service).
  - I do not whether I have to use `identity` parameter in `client_credentials` flow.

**Main Code Snippet**

```cs
MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File);

var appInfo = new ApplicationInfo{
    ApplicationId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppPrincipalId"],
    ApplicationName = "App name",
    ApplicationVersion = "1.0.0",
};

var authDelegate = new AuthDelegateImplementation(appInfo);
var fileProfileSettings = new FileProfileSettings("mip_data", false,
    authDelegate, new ConsentDelegateImplementation(), appInfo, LogLevel.Trace);

var fileProfile = MIP.LoadFileProfileAsync(fileProfileSettings).Result;
var engineSettings = new FileEngineSettings("engine-id", "", "en-US"){
    Identity = new Identity($"{appInfo.ApplicationId}@<TENANT-NAME>"){
        DelegatedEmail = "<OWNER>@<TENANT-NAME>",
    },
};
var fileEngine = fileProfile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings).Result;
var fileHandler = fileEngine.CreateFileHandlerAsync("c:\\sample.docx", "0", true).Result;
fileHandler.SetProtection(new ProtectionDescriptor("<TEMPLATE-ID>"));
var success = fileHandler.CommitAsync("c:\\encrypted.docx").Result;
```

**AuthDelegateImplementation**

```cs
public string AcquireToken(Identity identity, string authority, string resource)
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority + "/" + "<TENANT_ID>");
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential("<CLENT_ID>", "<CLIENT_SECRET>");
    var res = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);
    return res.AccessToken;
}
```

**ConsentDelegateImplementation**

```cs
public class ConsentDelegateImplementation : IConsentDelegate {
    public Consent GetUserConsent(string url) {
        return Consent.Accept;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams that after testing MIP's local persistent state (see FileProfileSettings.Path property when UseInMemoryStorage is flase) was corrupted. After removing "mip_data" folder issue disappeared.

Comment: I am getting this issue while setting label on PDF file. Removing the folder did not help. Still wondering what might be it

Comment: Can we apply custom email address as watermark content instead from protection.office.com ?